# Equal length dashed lines while using 'segments_to_lines' in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style

I want to create tapered lines with a dashed line stroke (to style intermittent streams).
I followed [this tutorial](https://anitagraser.com/2017/04/17/better-river-styles-with-tapered-lines/) to create the taperered lines, basically using `Geometry generator` with the expression `segments_to_lines($geometry)` and added the following stroke width expression:

```
CASE
  WHEN @geometry_part_num < 15 THEN  (0.222750 * (@geometry_part_num / 15))
  ELSE 0.22750
END
```

The result is as it is supposed to be:[image]

But when I style the tapered lines with a dashed line stroke the dashes (and spaces) have very varied lengths (I assume due to `segments_to_lines($geometry)`):[image]
For reference, this is how the dashed lines are supposed to look:[image]

Does anybody have an idea how I could achieve this effect while having the line tapered?

Comment: The dash pattern starts over at the beginning of each segment. I don't know of any way to have the pattern continue uninterrupted across multiple segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This effect occurs because of the different spacing between the line vertices. Try using the [Densify by interval](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisdensifygeometriesgivenaninterval) tool to make the vertices more evenly spaced on the line. Some test results are shown in the images below.

As commented by [@sidapo_cartisan](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/126287/sidapo-cartisan) expression may be inserted directly in the geometry generator code: `segments_to_lines( densify_by_distance($geometry, distance))`

```
               Original line                            Densified line
```

[image: 1 Line] [image: 2 Densified line]

[image: 3 Line (vert)] [image: 4 Densified line (vert)]

Comment: Thank you, this works well. For anyone else interested in this: I added the expression directly in the geometry generator code: `segments_to_lines(densify_by_distance($geometry,_distance_))`